# How can I open a URL without specifying HTTP or HTTPS in iOS?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

In my iOS app I am opening links using the code below:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",myurl]]];
```

The links come dynamically and HTTP/HTTPS is not provided.

I cannot hardcode HTTP or HTTPS because I don't know if the URL has HTTP or HTTPS. How can I open a URL without specifying HTTP or HTTPS?

Comment: I fail to see the problem! Where do you want / dont want to handle https/http?

Comment: Opening HTTP will always work, websites that require HTTPS will redirect.

Comment: @yene ...try youtube it will not work on http

Comment: Tested it and it opened youtube in the browser and redirected to HTTPS.

Comment: @anfahamid I agree with Yannick, this is common practice. People don't usually start their URLs with writing `https://`, so web devs generally implement a redirection.

Answer (score 9):

Solution for Swift:

```
let urlString = "example.com"
let urlHasHttpPrefix = urlString.hasPrefix("http://")
let urlHasHttpsPrefix = urlString.hasPrefix("https://")
let validUrlString = (urlHasHttpPrefix || urlHasHttpsPrefix) ? urlString : "http://\(urlString)"
```

Answer (score 9):

I think this a better approach than the ones presented here, since it avoids string comparison & manipulation.

```swift
public extension URL {
  var sanitise: URL {
    if var components = URLComponents(url: self, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false) {
      if components.scheme == nil {
        components.scheme = "http"
      }

      return components.url ?? self
    }

    return self
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Who said you don't know whether url contain http or not? You can find out...

In `prefixheader.pch` write below.

```
#define contains(str1, str2) ([str1 rangeOfString: str2 ].location != NSNotFound)
```

Then in your .m write below.

```
if (!contains(myurl, "http")) {
    myurl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@", myurl];
}
```

You are done!!!

Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: As per your answer i can check if http or https is there but my question is not this.You are providing http hard code what if instead of http it will be https,like in case of youtube it will not open on http but on https.

Answer (score 2):

Matching with `rangeOfString` is not a good approach.
You can match it as:

```
NSString *urlScheme = [url scheme];
  if (urlScheme == nil) {
    url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@",urlString]];
  }
```

And you don't have to worry about whether it's `http` or `https`. whenever you'll hit a url on `http` it'll automatically redirects to `https`