# How can l make redirect without adding HTTP/HTTPS?

Tags: swift, redirect, swift5

My task is to make redirect to instagram in different formats:

1. https://www.instagram,
2. instagram.com

Now it only works in the first case, when I add "https://".

Maybe you know, how can l achieve correct work without "https" too?

```
case .instagram:
        if let redirectionURl = URL(string: "instagram://user?username=\(url.lastPathComponent)"), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(redirectionURl) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(redirectionURl, options: [:])
            return
        }
```

Comment: Hope this helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33798011/how-can-i-open-a-url-without-specifying-http-or-https-in-ios

Answer (score 3):

Try this, you can check for prefix and if it's not there then you can append it.

```
let urlString = "instagram.com"
let validUrlString = urlString.hasPrefix("https") ? urlString : "https://\(urlString)"
```

Comment: I'm trying to do this, but it isn't working without "https" :(

`case .instagram:
            let urlString = "instagram.com:/user?username=\(url.lastPathComponent)"
            if let validUrlString = URL(string: urlString.hasPrefix("https") ? urlString : "https://\(urlString)"),
               UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(validUrlString) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(validUrlString, options: [:])
                return
        }`

Comment: Here's your solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35104054/swift-uiwebview-not-loading-http-sites#:~:text=2%20Answers&text=This%20is%20due%20to%20the,as%20it%20secures%20your%20app.